# Handle Error for Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I am facing issue when i got exception in threading. My Code is as follows:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask(taskId, ComputeBackgroundAdjudication));
```

And ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask method is as follows:

```
private void ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask(long taskId, Action<int> completedAdjudicationJobHandler)
{
    //My Logic           
    completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1);
}
```

Now what iam facing issue is in my logic suppose some exception is coming i want to log into some text file.
After i searched in net i found some answer is as follows.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask(taskId, ComputeBackgroundAdjudication))
.ContinueWith(
    task =>
    {
        if (task.Exception != null)
            task.Exception.Handle(ex =>
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C://test.txt", "Error:" + ex.Message + "\r\n");
                return true;
            });
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
);
```

Now its logging into text file. After logging into text file the thread is not starting again. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "The thread is not starting again"? Where are you trying to start the "thread" again?

Comment: If i will start new thread then what will happen to the current running thread?

Comment: What's wrong with a good old fashined try catch? Why do you need to log in a seperate thread? Log in the same thread then return.

Comment: Can you edit my example and give me the solution.

Comment: @Prasad IMHO doing `ex.ToString()` is a lot beter than doing `ex.Message` because you may only get *"Error XXXXX happened, see inner exception for details"* in your log if you only do `ex.Message`, if you use `ex.ToString()` it also prints the inner exceptions and their messages (and stack traces too which are always useful)

Answer (score 1):

In your example the exception terminates the task/thread and after that you log the cause of the thread termination.

It seems what you are searching for is more of this kind:

```
private void ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask(long taskId, Action<int> completedAdjudicationJobHandler)
{
     while(true) {
         try {
             //My Logic           
             completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1);
         }
         catch(Exception ex) {
             System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C://test.txt", "Error:" + ex.ToString() + "\r\n");
         }
     }
}
```

But this seems as if whatever completedAdjudicationJobHandler does is not really well designed.

I want to add: If whatever throws the exception will always throw the exception this leads to an infinite loop.

Edit 2016-01-07: Maybe I misunderstood the wanted effect again. As I understand the last comment you want to do things written at the position of // MyLogic and whether they fail or succeed want completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1); executed. In this case the code example would be:

```
private void ComputeBackgroundAdjudicationTask(long taskId, Action<int> completedAdjudicationJobHandler)
{
    try {
        //My Logic
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C://test.txt", "Error:" + ex.ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
    finally {
        completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is throwing error near to catch(Exception ex) {
             ex.Handle(ex =>

Comment: What error? Can you give a more detailed error message?Besides I want to emphasize that this is no good idea. It can lead to threads with an endless loop.
Just wanted to give you an idea.

Comment: @dryman, seeing as you're using `ex.Handle` your `ex` should have probably been of type `AggregateException`. This still baffles me though as synchronous code (i.e. `completedAdjudicationJobHandler`) is very unlikely to throw it.

Comment: @Kirill Shlenskiy
Yeah I'm kind of dry coding. Edited the post.

Comment: In //My Logic i wrote code like int i = 0; int abc = 1/i;

Comment: Guys I was just recomposing already written code. ;D
All I wanted was to give an idea how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Prasad did it work or did you figure it out? Or in other words is still help needed?

Comment: @dryman Still i need help. Whatever u gave code that code is also not working. After logging into text file the current thread is stopping there only and its not going to next line of completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1);.

Comment: Then I guess I still don't understand what you are aiming for. Can you make some kind of flow chart to illustrate when and under which circumstances what should be executed?
And for reference: In which way does finally not work?

Comment: I have requirement like user can start n threads. Suppose he is getting any error that thread should not stop. It should pick the next data and it should work until the data is finished.

Comment: Ok follow-up question: When is completedAdjudicationJobHandler(1) supposed to happen? After each processing of data or at the end when all data sets are processed and the thread is going to exit?

Comment: After each processing of data

Comment: OK I have updated the first code example. Does this suit more your problem?
If so plaese beware of infinite loops and at least add some kind of cancelation or something like that. Otherwise you have to abort the thread and that can have ugly consequences.